# In a linear regression model, is the hat matrix H orthogonal to the residual?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression

I think they are orthogonal since $\hat{\epsilon} = (I-H)Y$ so $H\hat{\epsilon} = HY-HY = 0$, but is this the correct proof and how can think of this geometrically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This would be better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but there it would be closed as a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515874/why-are-the-residuals-in-mathbbrn-p/516880#516880

Comment: Now asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582998/in-a-linear-regression-model-is-the-hat-matrix-h-orthogonal-to-the-residual